# How to access to AWS CloudWatch from a local docker container?

Tags: node.js, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, amazon-cloudwatch

I've been struggling to test a local docker container that can access to AWS CloudWatch to push all the log streams that the nodejs express framework has generated.

I got the error when running docker-compose up

```
Error response from daemon: failed to create task for container: failed to initialize logging driver: failed to create Cloudwatch log stream: operation error CloudWatch Logs: CreateLogStream, failed to sign request: failed to retrieve credentials: failed to refresh cached credentials, no EC2 IMDS role found, operation error ec2imds: GetMetadata, request canceled, context deadline exceeded
```

And I also have tried to follow the steps that on https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/a-guide-to-locally-testing-containers-with-amazon-ecs-local-endpoints-and-docker-compose/
, but still got the same error.

*Is there any solutions to test local docker container before deploying to EC2?*
Thank you :-)

**here's my index.js of express framework**

```
import express from 'express'

const app = express()

console.log('process.env.STAGE:', process.env.STAGE)

app.get('/test1', async (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    throw new Error('An error occurred in the test1.');
  } catch (error) {
    console.log('error:', error)
    throw error;
  }
})

app.get('/test2', async (req, res, next) => {
  console.log('test2')
  res.status(200).json('test2')
})

app.use((err, req, res, next) => {
  console.error('Error:', err.message);
  res.status(500).json({ error: err.message });
})

app.listen(8080)
```

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM node:14

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm install

COPY . .

EXPOSE 8080

CMD [ "node", "index.js" ]
```

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '3'

services:
  nodejs:
    container_name: test-express
    build: .
    ports:
      - "80:8080" 
    environment:
      - PORT=80
      - STAGE=dev
      - REGION=${region}
      - AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=${AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID}
      - AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=${AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY}
    command: node index.js
    logging:
      driver: awslogs
      options:
        awslogs-region: ap-northeast-1
        awslogs-group: ...
        awslogs-create-group: "true"
```

**docker-compose.override.yml**

```
version: "3"
networks:
    # This special network is configured so that the local metadata
    # service can bind to the specific IP address that ECS uses
    # in production
    credentials_network:
        driver: bridge
        ipam:
            config:
                - subnet: "169.254.170.0/24"
                  gateway: 169.254.170.1
services:
    # This container vends credentials to your containers
    ecs-local-endpoints:
        # The Amazon ECS Local Container Endpoints Docker Image
        image: amazon/amazon-ecs-local-container-endpoints
        volumes:
          # Mount /var/run so we can access docker.sock and talk to Docker
          - /var/run:/var/run
          # Mount the shared configuration directory, used by the AWS CLI and AWS SDKs
          # On Windows, this directory can be found at "%UserProfile%\.aws"
          - $HOME/.aws/:/home/.aws/
        environment:
          # define the home folder; credentials will be read from $HOME/.aws
          HOME: "/home"
          # You can change which AWS CLI Profile is used
          AWS_PROFILE: "default"
        networks:
            credentials_network:
                # This special IP address is recognized by the AWS SDKs and AWS CLI 
                ipv4_address: "169.254.170.2"
                
    # Here we reference the application container that we are testing
    # You can test multiple containers at a time, simply duplicate this section
    # and customize it for each container, and give it a unique IP in 'credentials_network'.
    nodejs:
        depends_on:
            - ecs-local-endpoints
        networks:
            credentials_network:
                ipv4_address: "169.254.170.3"
        environment:
          AWS_DEFAULT_REGION: "ap-northeast-1"
          AWS_CONTAINER_CREDENTIALS_RELATIVE_URI: "/creds"
```

Comment: I have the same problem. Were you able to solve the issue

Comment: anyone got solution for this?